# Categorize a 'string' column based on the text word present in it using pre-defined categories in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science, categories

I have a pandas column having email domain, something like this:

```
Sno  Domain_IDs
1   herowire.com
2   xyzenerergy.com
3   financial.com
4   oo-loans.com
5   okwire.com
6   cleaneneregy.com
7   pop-advisors.com
```

and so on....

I have the following caterogies in a separate dataframe:

```
Sno category
1   contains wire
2   contains energy
3   contains loans
4   contains advisors
```

I want to create a dataframe which categorizes the data as follow:

```
Sno Domain_IDS         category
1   herowire.com       contains wire
2   xyzenerergy.com    contains energy
3   financial.com      others
4   oo-loans.com       contains loans
5   okwire.com         contains wire
6   cleaneneregy.com   contains energy
7   pop-advisors.com   contains advisors
```

I tried using lambda functions and standard loop using "if else" statements, by using

```
"emailAddress.str.contains('wire')"
```

contains clause, but I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Somehow i am not able to parse the single line of text in the dataframe. Kindly help.

Comment: What about wire-loans.com or energy-advisors.com?  Do they only have one cateogry-- if so, which one?

Comment: which ever word comes first will work for me I think. It can be in either category. No differentiation as such. Though i would be interested in seeing how I can differentiate in them. Thanks @SourceSimian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find a pattern in domains, extract and create category

```
pat =  '('+'|'.join(cat['Sno category'].str.split().str[-1])+')'
df['category'] = ('contains ' + df['Domain_IDs'].str.extract(pat)).fillna('other')

   Sno  Domain_IDs          category
0   1   herowire.com        contains wire
1   2   xyzenenergy.com     contains energy
2   3   financial.com       other
3   4   oo-loans.com        contains loans
4   5   okwire.com          contains wire
5   6   cleaneneregy.com    other
6   7   pop-advisors.com    contains advisors
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do have another question, if you are willing to answer. How can we leverage NLP in this to create categories on its own? Like for example, one category not mentioned above is "services", how to automatically make this category based on the times its seen in the domain. Any idea ?

Comment: @KshitijYadav, its a completely different question. You will get better answers if you post a new question for that

Comment: Hi @Vaishali , could you help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190428/categorize-a-column-using-a-dictionary-key-multiple-values-pair

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ["wire", "energy", "loans","advisors"]
def fun(a):
    for i in lst:
        if i in a:
            return i
    return "others"
df["category"] = df.Domain_IDs.apply(lambda x: fun(x))
df

  Sno        Domain_IDs category
0   1      herowire.com     wire
1   2   xyzenenergy.com   energy
2   3     financial.com   others
3   4      oo-loans.com    loans
4   5        okwire.com     wire
5   6   cleanenergy.com   energy
6   7  pop-advisors.com advisors
```

Comment: So this method doesn’t handle multiple categories

Answer (score 1):

This solution allows for multiple categorizations:

```
categories = pd.DataFrame({"category": ["wire", "energy", "loans", "advisors"]})
domains = pd.DataFrame({"Sno": list(range(1, 10)),
                        "Domain_IDs": [
                            "herowire.com",
                            "xyzenergy.com",
                            "financial.com",
                            "oo-loans.com",
                            "okwire.com",
                            "cleanenergy.com",
                            "pop-advisors.com",
                            "energy-advisors.com",
                            "wire-loans.com"]})    
categories["common"] = 0
domains["common"] = 0

possibilities = pd.merge(categories, domains, how="outer")
possibilities["satisfied"] = possibilities.apply(lambda row: row["category"] in row["Domain_IDs"], axis=1)
```

So filtering only categories which are satisfied:

```
possibilities[possibilities["satisfied"]]
```

gives:

```
    category  common           Domain_IDs  Sno satisfied
0       wire       0         herowire.com    1      True
4       wire       0           okwire.com    5      True
8       wire       0       wire-loans.com    9      True
10    energy       0        xyzenergy.com    2      True
14    energy       0      cleanenergy.com    6      True
16    energy       0  energy-advisors.com    8      True
21     loans       0         oo-loans.com    4      True
26     loans       0       wire-loans.com    9      True
33  advisors       0     pop-advisors.com    7      True
34  advisors       0  energy-advisors.com    8      True
```