# Categorize a column using a Dictionary key - multiple values pair

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, logic

I have a dictionary:

```py
{'Consulting': {'Deloitte', 'EY', 'KPMG', 'PwC'},
'Education': {'.edu', 'College', 'University'},
'Government':{'state','.gov','city'},
'Corporate':{'corpor','consumer','care'},
...... etc.}
```

I have a dataframe:

```
 Sno  Text            column1    column2 ......
  1   Deloitte.com
  2   Texas.gov
  3   smi@EY.com
  4   UTD.edu
  5   rapper@corporate.com

 ..... etc.
```

I want to use the dictionary to categorize the dataframe and build a column Category, like this:

```
 Sno  Text                   Category       column1    column2 ......
  1   Deloitte.com           Consulting
  2   Texas.gov              Government
  3   smi@EY.com             Consulting
  4   UTD.edu                Education
  5   rapper@corporate.com   Corporate
 ..... etc.
```

How can I utilize the dictionary with multiple values in python to find a full phrase or part of the phrase in the Text column and categorize it? Can we also use the same logic in case 2 matches exist? What will happen then?

Also, might sound vague, but the reason I am using Dictionary is that we can map multiple values to one category, is there a better way to do it without the dictionary?

Comment: [k for k, v in dictionary.items() if v in col_value] should get all the matches. Assuming only one match exists, get the 0th index. You can then use df[“text”].apply(lambda ...). Forgive typos - I’m on my phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC after re-create your `dict`  do with `findall`, then map it back

```
newdict = {i: k for k, v in d.items() for i in v}
df.Text.str.findall('|'.join(newdict.keys())).str[0].map(newdict)
Out[431]: 
0    Consulting
1    Government
2    Consulting
3     Education
4     Corporate
Name: Text, dtype: object

df['cate']=df.Text.str.findall('|'.join(newdict.keys())).str[0].map(newdict)
```

Comment: Can you edit the code to find wildcards? For example, instead of Corporate we have Corpor, I still want to tag that as corporate. Some thing in the terms of ".str.contains()"

Comment: @KshitijYadav this is involved natural language process , you may need find what type of abbreviation you have in your real data

Comment: Got it. One last question, what about a time when given name satisfy two condition? Like it has corporate.edu which means it would satisfy condition for both Corporate and Education. How would we deal with that

Comment: @KshitijYadav`[newdict[y] for y in x ]for x in df.Text.str.findall('|'.join(newdict.keys()))]`

Comment: What happens if we want to categorize those “not found” row into “Others” ?

Comment: Hello @BEN_YO - Sorry to necromance this a little, but I came through your post and hoped to have found an efficient way to classify a massive DF. 
I tried recreating your answer, however, my dict contains a few regex patterns, not just "hardcoded" k:v's. What would be the most efficient way to go about this, in your opinion? (so far I've been doing this looping through a one-level dictionary's items and assigning value for every str.contain[ing] key)

Comment: I'm using this answer as a model for solving my problem. However, as I want all the matches (initially), I dropped the str[0]. 

It occurred to me that I don't understand the `map(newdict)` at the end. What is the purpose of that?

Comment: @tim.rohrer it is for protect the string findall in here return the dict key, if you would like have the dict value as output you need map it

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using `re` and `np.vectorize`:

```
cat = re.compile('|'.join(f"(?P<{k}>{'|'.join(v)})" for k,v in categories.items()))
df['category'] = np.vectorize(lambda x: cat.search(x).lastgroup)(df.text)
```

This gave me:

```
                   text    category
0          Deloitte.com  Consulting
1             Texas.gov  Government
2            smi@EY.com  Consulting
3               UTD.edu   Education
4  rapper@corporate.com   Corporate
```

Basically I create a regex string consisting of the category dict keys as group names, and values as a pattern delimited by `|` <sub>meaning `or`</sub>. Then vectorize is used to map this regex search to each item getting the cooresponding group name found

Comment: Hey Jab, what about a time when given name satisfy two condition? Like it has corporate.edu which means it would satisfy condition for both Corporate and Education. How would we deal with that